# Android webview to load desktop view

Tags: android-webview, user-agent

I want the android web view to display the desktop website rather than mobile website.
Even after setting the user agent to desktop, still I see the mobile site being loaded.

```
String newUA = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";

WebSettings webSettings2 = webDisqus.getSettings();
        webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings2.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webDisqus.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webDisqus.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webDisqus.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webDisqus.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        webDisqus.loadUrl("http://www.philly.com");
```

Please help to display to the desktop website rather than mobile website

Comment: You can use `setDesktopMode(true)` from [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) or read how it's [implemented](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sites use a variety of mechanisms to decide to serve a mobile version of a page; the user agent is just one of them. They may set a cookie or some other piece of state that will always redirect to the mobile page after you've visited once. They might look at screen dimensions and do it that way. It's very hard to say what this particular website is doing. Maybe try clearing cookies?

Are you certain that the UA you have set is a desktop UA that the site recognises as a desktop browser?

Comment: I tried to clear the data in settings, and it seemed to work. Thanks for the points it might be helpful next time if setting desktop UA doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setDesktopMode(true)` from [this `WebView` subclass](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) or implement something similar to [setDesktopMode()](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358) using the following `WebView` methods:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(MODIFIED_OR_DESKTOP_USERAGENT);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

This code (a) modifies the user-agent *not* to include the words "mobile" or "Android" and (b) adjusts the viewport to a larger width.

Comment: While referencing a link in a comment to save space and retain formatting makes sense, answers should include the code block in case the link expires.

Comment: @AbandonedCart But you also can’t just copy somebody *else’s* copyrighted code and re-license it arbitrarily (here: CC BY-SA 4.0).

Comment: @AbandonedCart Threatening that you could have done worse things does not help much. And the guidelines certainly don’t ask you to break laws. Finally, you’re also wrong about the MIT License and its requirements for attribution. You should read up on the MIT License (and probably other licenses), but in short, it requires that a copy of both the license and copyright notice must be included. Anyway, your latest edit looks better.

Comment: I was not threatening, simply pointing out that it was an effort to assist you. I actually did read up on the MIT license before posting about it, but I see no benefit in being the target of misplaced aggression.